# Partial Matching a list of values to dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I am trying to clean a dataframe of raw contact information. The raw data gives a person's title and based on the title I need to determine a level of seniority. If the title has a partial match to the dictionary key, I need to append the value for that key to a new list. Essentially I need to iterate through each title in the list and see if there is a partial match to any dictionary key and grab the corresponding dictionary value and append that value to a new list. I've tried multiple formats of for loops and list comprehension but no luck.

Here's an example of the list and dict:

```
title = ['CEO', 'CFO', 'Financial Analyst', 'Associate', 'Tax Manager', 'Audit Manager']
seniority_dict = {'CEO':'Exec', 'CFO':'Exec', 'Manager':'Manager', 'Analyst':'Associate', 'Associate':'Associate'}
```

Here's what the seniority should be for the corresponding values in the list above

```
seniority = ['Exec', 'Exec', 'Associate', 'Associate', 'Manager', 'Manager']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't have key not in title

```
title = ['Software Engineer', 'CEO', 'CFO', 'Financial Analyst', 'QA Engineer', 'Associate', 'Tax Manager', 'Audit Manager']
seniority_dict = {'CEO': 'Exec', 'CFO': 'Exec', 'Manager': 'Manager', 'Analyst': 'Associate', 'Associate': 'Associate'}

new_list = []
for t in title:
    found = False
    for key, value in seniority_dict.items():
        if key in t:
            new_list.append(value)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        new_list.append('NaN')
print(new_list)
```

Comment: This works, thank you! how would account for titles that don't have match to a key. I would want those to be equal to nan so the length of the new list is equal to the length of the title list

Comment: forgot to tag sorry

Comment: @ParthPatel Updated my answer. you can append as per your requirement.